# Find not working if date formatting is done at custom formatter in jqgrid

Tags: search, jqgrid, formatter

I am doing the date formatting by extending the jqgrid fmatter in my custom formatter. If I do like that then the "Find" functionality is not working. Below is the sample colModel and custom formatter function.

```
colModel = {name:currentLevelInDate, label:"Period Beginning (GMT)", index:currentLevelInDate,sorttype: "date",datefmt: datefmt, formatter:"formatDate",
unformat: 'unformatDate', formatoptions: { newformat:newFormat, srcformat:srcFormat}}

formatDate : function(cellvalue, opts, rowObject) {
...
...
var op = $.extend({}, $.jgrid.formatter.date);
if(opts.colModel.formatoptions != undefined) {
    op = $.extend({}, op, opts.colModel.formatoptions);
}

cellDisplayValue = $.fmatter.util.DateFormat(op.srcformat,cellvalue,op.newformat,op);
....

return cellDisplayValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should post more full code which you use. For example you use variables `datefmt`, `newFormat`, `srcFormat`, but you don't included the definition of the variables.

One clear error in your code is that usage of function names as strings:

```js
formatter: "formatDate"
```

instead of usage as variables: `formatter: formatDate`. The syntax `formatter: "formatDate"` will be correct only if `formatDate` were defined as the property of `$.fn.fmatter` object. If you do this then you should include the full code which shows exactly what you do. One can't find the error in your code if you posts only code fragments where you suspect the error exists. The best would be posting full code which could be used to reproduce your problem.